# Create a square border, with image inside and width and height dependent to uniform grid colum

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, uniformgrid

I think this is a little tricky problem.

I have a ListBox that must present some images and each image must be put inside a rectangle or a square border. This is simple, I know. The fact is that this listbox must show always 3 elements per row, whether the screen resolution or window size.

In order to obtain it I've templated the listbox like this:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="_productsLB" SelectedIndex="0"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="4"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="8"
                    Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Uniform"/>                        
                </Border>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The problem is that I obtain a rectangular border around the image instead of a square border "around" the listboxitem.

Remember that I can't specifiy width property because they must be dependent to the uniform grid column width.

Do you have some hints?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What if you remove Width="Auto" Height="Auto" and change the HorizontalAlignment to "Center"?

Comment: Same identical result :/

Comment: What if you put a grid inside the border, h/v alignment stretch and then the image is set to h/v alignment centre?

Comment: Or failing that put the grid on the outside and then set the border width/height to bind to the actualwidth/actualheight of the grid using a relative source binding

Comment: @BobVale nothing changes for your first option, for the second one I don't know ho to bind it to the columnwidth. I've tried
{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource DataTemplate}} but without results

Comment: Your Listbox item is an Image and i think your problem is that you have set a Margin = "8" on your border, your could set it to zero and set the Margin on your Image instead.

Comment: @BigL nope, same result.

Comment: I have come up with the same solution as BigL suggests: Removing the margin of the border stretches it exactly as large as a listviewItem is.
Perhaps post a picture of what you expect your desired result to look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Removing the Margin from the border and setting it on the Image, creates a Border around the Image which is exactly as big as a ListviewItem is. See picture.

If that is not what you expected, please define more clearly.

```
  <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="8"
          Width="Auto" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

**EDIT:**

Add `VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to your ListBox and the images should resize properly. See picture below.

**EDIT II:**

If you want the images to appear as squares, you have to set the Border's Height to its current Width:

```
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

[image: Border around images]

Comment: This is the result I'd like, but the images I'm trying to show have different resolutions (the reason for uniform stretch). In this solution you're using standard Windows backgrounds, and they all are 1024*768 images. My images have various sizes. Some are in a portrait format others in landscape and others are almost squared.
I've tried your suggestions but the result do not change.
Are you sure that this should work even with images with different aspect ratio?

Comment: OK, now I understand your issue. See my edit and try that out.

Comment: is it the image or are those borders rectangular, I thought the OP wanted them square?

Comment: @Bob You're correct, I didn't set the Border height to be square. fixed that similar to your approach

Comment: That works fine.I'm sorry if it wasn't clear. With "square" I meant that width = height. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="_productsLB" SelectedIndex="0" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"> 
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel> 
        <ItemsPanelTemplate> 
            <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="4"/> 
        </ItemsPanelTemplate> 
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel> 
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate> 
            <Grid>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="8" 
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Grid}}" Height="="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Grid}}" > 
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Uniform" />                         
            </Border>
            </Grid>                    
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ListBox>
```